# Shared instances in Self-Referencing Singleton

Tags: c#, singleton, self-reference

When I try to define a self-referencing Singleton as follows:

```cs
class Singleton<T> where T : Singleton<T> { protected static T singletonInstance; ... }
```

Implementing the singleton class works fine when I derive it using a non-generic class like this:

```cs
class Derived : Singleton<Derived> { ... }
```

However when I try to derive the singleton via a generic class like so:

```cs
class Derived<T> : Singleton<Derived<T>> { ... }
```

And then implement the generic classes:

```cs
class DerivedChildA : Derived<int> { ... }
```

```cs
class DerivedChildB : Derived<int> { ... }
```

Instead of getting individual singleton instances of `DerivedChildA` and `DerivedChildB`, there is only one singleton instance of `Derived<int>` type shared between the 2 child classes.

I would rather not have `DerivedChildA` and `DerivedChildB` to derive from `Singleton<T>` directly. So how should I go about modifying my class declarations to obtain individual singleton instances of `DerivedChildA` and `DerivedChildB` (in other words, `Singleton<DerivedChildA>` and `Singleton<DerivedChildB>`) ?

---

Edit: As pointed out by Varun, this method of self-referencing singletons does produce unique singleton instances when the argument T type is different, such as with

```cs
class DerivedChildC : Derived<string> { ... }
class DerivedChildD : Derived<double> { ... }
```

However my project requires `DerivedChildA` and `DerivedChildB` to have the exact same generic type `Derived<int>` , and unfortunately I'm not able to change this requirement. :(

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand what's happening here. The static field is shared among all the instances of a real type. A generic definition is not a real type; a real type is created As soon as you provide a concrete generic type argument for the generic parameter. So in this case this happens as soon as you say:

`: Derived<int>`

or even if you inherit directly from Singleton:

`: Singleton<int>`

Once the type is generated for a generic definition, it's static (Instance in your example) field will be shared across all derived types

This can be proven by a slightly different example, by changing the argument for generic parameter T.  So instead if you have

`class DerivedChildA : Derived<int>`

And

`class DerivedChildB : Derived<decimal>`

You'll have two separate real types generated as the base and hence the static Instance field will also be separate for instances of both A and B.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see your point about using a generic argument T type in the DerivedChild classes to separate the instances. It is also the way I have been using this Singleton up till now. However, I've recently had to declare two classes with the exact same argument T type, which caused the shared singleton instance problem to pop up.

Comment: @nyaow can you change Derived<T> from which child A/B are inheriting? You can declare it as Derived<T1, T2> and DerivedChildA : Derived<int, DerivedChildA> where T2 would be the final type, to serve no purpose other than causing real base type to be different. Not something one would like, but then if you can't change the base architecture you're left with little options.

Comment: Yes, I can make changes to Derived<T> and Singleton<T>. That sounds like a possible way to go about it. Technically I can make changes to the base architecture. The only parts I can't change are the functionality of `DerivedChildA` and `DeriedChildB`.